# Shortest distance from multiple points to one point

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

I am looking for an algorithm to find the shortest distance from multiple nodes to one end node. For example let $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_r$ be the nodes on a graph with distance $d_1,d_2,\dots,d_r$ to the end node $v$. I want the shortest $d$ to $v$.

Comment: By (the usual) default, a graph means undirected graph. Can you clarify that _in the question_?

Answer (score 2):

This is quite straightforward

- Reverse the direction of each edge.
- Apply single source shortest path algorithm with destination as the source.
- Reverse the direction again. (Optional, only if you want to preserve the originality of graph)

**Time Complexity**-
With graph given as adjacency list, it takes $O(E+V)$ to reverse the directions of each edge. With graph given as adjacency matrix, it takes $\theta(V^2)$. Rest you can apply any single source shortest path algorithm like Dijkshtra.

Note that a graph with reverse edges of original one typically called as **transpose** of the original graph.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new vertex $s$ to your graph and give it an edge to each of $v_1, \dots, v_r$. Then use your favourite shortest path algorithm to compute the shortest path from $s$ to $v$. That path has length $1+\min\{d_1, \dots, d_r\}$.